# How to use the same object model for 2 databases with the same table structure?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring-boot (2.1.1.RELEASE) and hibernate jpa to sync a table from one environment to another environment. Both of the tables are in mysql databases of identical versions. The table structure is identical between environments. For example, I have an entity object like this:

```
@Entity
class Ping {
   Long pingId;
   String userId;
}

@Repository
class PingDao  extends JpaRepository<PingNotificationData, Long> {

}

@Service
class PingService {

   void syncPing(){
      // copy pings from Ping table in one database
      // insert pings to Ping table in another database
   }    
}
```

How to configure the same dao, object model class to use different data databases for different environments?

Comment: Something like this. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases You'd have to wire both JpaRepos with different datasources.

Comment: I saw those similar examples and it looks like it needs different domain object and spring set them base on the package scan of different objects. Do you have example that share the same domain object? like one domain object, one dao, just 2 different datasources.

Comment: Something like this can help - https://dzone.com/articles/multiple-databases-with-shared-entity-classes-in-s, the idea is to set the packagesToScan to the same entity package in both the datasources.